# How to start into Thunderbird Addon Development

Tags: documentation, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I want to implement a Thunderbird-Addon and already found information on the mozilla web pages regarding Addon Development. However, some of the information is rather confusing, and thus I have some more specific questions:

1) Are Firefox Addon development and Thunderbird Addon development related? Some links may suggest so, others are indicated as "outdated"...

2) On the Mozilla web pages there are infos related to addons for Thunderbird 2,3, or 5. Isn't Thunderbird at version 31 currently? Probably I missed something here.

3) I want to extend the tagging mechanics in thunderbird, e.g. allowing relationships between tags, tag hierarchies etc. For that I would have to extend the existing data model. Can I do so?

4) Is there a good overview of the actual data model? Before I start programming something, I'd like to see which parts I have to touch and which I can leave alone.